# cdn-chat.sstatic down, 500 error on loading master-chat.js

Tags: bug, chat, cdn

Well, title says everything. Trying to get the `http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Js/master-chat.js` script fails with a 500 error which won't allow you to change/join rooms at all. Pls fix :(

Actually all the `http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/` subdirectory returns 500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue with the build's static content output in Oregon which changing our CDN's source pull exposed - this was reverted to New York, corrected in Oregon, and not re-pointed to Oregon to pull all fresh content.

This error should not be happening anymore, but please alert us if you see any other issues.

Comment: "not re-pointed" or "now re-pointed"? Not sure enough to edit myself... :)